# Number of irreducible components in an intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

Is the number of irreducible components of an irreducible projective variety $V$ over an algebraically closed field with any linear subspace $L$ always least than $\deg(V)$? I think so but I didn't manage to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. The degree of the intersection is the same as the degree of $V$ so, since any component has at least degree $1$, we can have at most $\deg V$ components, counted with multiplicity.

Comment: Sorry for the naive question, but what if $L \cap V$ contains a component of dimension $ \leq \dim V - 2$ ? Such component will contribute to a degree zero right ?

Comment: Over an algebraically closed field, the intersection of an irreducible projective variety $V$ with a linear subspace has always all the components of the same dimension (namely, $\dim V - \mathrm{codim}\, L)$. In fact, this is true for hyperplane sections (that are effective divisors) and the general result follows by induction on $\mathrm{codim}\, L$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_section

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! (and +1)

Comment: Ok I knew the result only for hyperplanes, and I did not realize every irreducible component have same dimension, so I did not manage to handle the induction step.

Comment: I think that in order to have every component of $L\cap V$ of dimension $\dim V - \operatorname{codim} L$ the space $L$ needs to be somehow general: there could be some issues with degenerate components. For example, if $V\subseteq \mathbb{P}^3$ is a smooth quadric and $L\subseteq V$ is a line. However it is always true that the dimension of every component is at least $\dim V - \operatorname{codim} L$.